# How to read a nonlocal excel with PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have the following problem, the project is that a run will be placing data in excel and these data must be on a page monitoring , the tool I'm using is the PHPExcel library works without problem, the problem is the user will have the excel on your machine and the page will be on the server so you should be able to connect to the user's computer but by placing the address the library has problems, I do not know if any other function to help me redirect , now I exercise locally and does not work.

Don't problem:

```
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("D.xlsx");
```

With Problem:

```
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("localhost:8081/excel/ticket/D.xlsx");
```

Or

```
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("10.204.8.14:8081/excel/ticket/D.xlsx");
```

Message:

Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could not open localhost:8081/excel/ticket/D.xlsx for reading! File does not exist.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\excel\ticket\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php:347 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\excel\ticket\prueba.php(15): PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007->load('localhost:8081/...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\libreria_excel\ticket\Classes\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php on line 347

The URL is OK.

Thank you very much and greetings!

Comment: you will need a file upload, so the user uploads the excel file to your server

Comment: You can't.... you will need to get the file to your webserver before you can load it